# Implementing Precision and Recall in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, metrics

I'm trying to understand how to implement the *precision* and the *recall* on my own. Given that `clf` is a classifier, `y_test[i]` is true value and `X_test[i].reshape(1,-1)` is the predicted value, are these definitions correct?

**Precision**

```
def testPosValueMetric(clf, X_test, y_test):
    success =0
    fail = 0
    for i in range(len(y_test)):
        if y_test[i] == 1:
            if clf.predict(X_test[i].reshape(1,-1)) == 1:
                success += 1
            else:
                fail +=1

    return (success/(success+fail))
```

**Recall**

```
def recall(clf, X_test, y_test):
    tp =0
    fp = 0
    for i in range(len(y_test)):
        if y_test[i] == 1:
            if clf.predict(X_test[i].reshape(1,-1)) == 1:
                tp += 1
            else:
                fp +=1

    tn =0
    fn = 0
    for i in range(len(y_test)):
        if y_test[i] == 0:
            if clf.predict(X_test[i].reshape(1,-1)) == 0:
                tn += 1
            else:
                fn +=1

    return (tp/(tp+fn))
```

Comment: be aware when you use division to get the final results because right now you use integer division

Comment: Also aware of divide by zero in some cases.